# Download progress bar is not changing progress in iOS enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, download, enterprise-distribution

I am developing and distributing iPad apps via enterprise distribution. They download and execute fine, so everything is ok (the web link, ipa file, plist file, provisioning...).

The "problem" is when the user clicks the link to download, the progress bar in the iPad showing the download progress reads "Waiting..." but is empty and never changes. When it is completed, it changes to "Installing..." and then it shows the installation progress correctly.

For small apps it is not really a problem, but for larger apps it makes the user think that nothing is happening.

Is there a way to show the downloading progress?

Comment: Of course there is...but without showing us your code we can't know what is going wrong.  I bet you are downloading on the main thread and blocking it while it waits to finish.  You need to make use of async callbacks.  Or just use AFNetworking to help you since it rocks.

Comment: Either I didn't explain clearly or you didn't understand. The problem is not in my code. It is when the user tries to install de app through a web link.

Comment: Oh, in that case...I have no clue...I doubt you have any control over that.  Perhaps your server is not reporting in a way that the device understands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior when downloading an app via ad-hoc distribution. You click on the link then you get the `Waiting...` and after you have the `Installing...`
To my knowledge it is not possible to change that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll wait just in case someone knows, then I'll leave it for impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the web server (Apache in this case) from gzip-ing the file
(which is useless anyway) enabled the progress indicator for me:

`# Don't compress images and compressed files`
`SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|mbtiles|zip|ipa|tgz|gz|bz2)$ no-gzip dont-vary`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem.

In my case, I setup the enterprise environment in my personal mac, place the ipa file in the web sharing folder, and create a app.plist and download html.

From mac, I created a network.

Then make iPhone join the network, access the html to download app.

However, the download progress bar was always waiting without progress.

I fixed the problem by changing the setting of wifi in the iphone to static ip, using the subnet 255.255.255.0.